# Compiling an ExtJS MVC app that uses Direct

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have the following case. In my not-compiled project I have included ( in html file) :

- extjs-all.js
- my api.js ( that generates the remote calls)
- app.js

When i compile my app i get one single file that contains extjs library and also my app files. I can't get it to work because i have no place to include my api.js. I can't included before all-classes.js because Ext.ns will not work. If i include after my all-classes.js than my stores will do not have instantieted the direct functions.

Have any idea? Do i have to keep separated the extjs library minified and the app files compilation?

Comment: Leave the extjs libraries as a separate file. It's not really a rule that you should only have 1 file. YSlow! says that it's ok to have 6 JS files and still get an A rating in their grading system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar;

- first comes the ExtJS libs
- second the API
- third my custom classes/extension (none of them uses the API)
- fourth comes the Models, Stores
- fifth the rest of your application

If this don't work you should do necessary refactorings to make it work cause you may end up with problems otherwise.

Comment: Where do you insert the Ext direct mapping? 
What re-factoring do you suggest in order to solve this problem otherwise.
What is the command that worked for you to compile without Ext

Comment: @catalinux bless me, again not entirely correct!! The API is on position third, not second.

Comment: When you say"fourth comes the Models, Stores , fifth the rest of your application" do you mean the classic MVC app?

Comment: @catalinux It can be any sort of application code. In the second part you may also maintain a internal order, but that is based on your insertions.

Comment: sra, i'm following the above answer, and for some reason, the ExtDirectRouter.ashx doesn't get called, but my ExtDirectProxy.ashx (aka API) does.  When would you have time to assist?

Comment: @MacGyver hmm, that sounds weird... so your ExtJS Direct provider is fully setup and registered after the API call?